# Bootstrap icons (Glyphicons) are positioned slightly up when using Google Fonts, how can I solve that issue?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, document, google-font-api, glyphicons

If I add the following Google Fonts in the head tag of the document

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli|Dosis:500,400|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
```

Bootstrap icons (Glyphicons) are positioned slightly up, as You can see at this link: http://www.acarrilho.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/icon_off.png

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: See this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273500/center-twitter-bootstrap-3-glyphicons-in-buttons

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the problem is about Google font but instead the combination of font-size and vertical-align. The default font-size of icon's in Bootstrap is 14px and in the declaration for `icon-` we have `vertical-align: text-top;`, see code below.

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  *margin-right: .3em;
  line-height: 14px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
  background-position: 14px 14px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

In your "Dashboard" button it seems like the font-size is larger than 14px, maybe 22px? One solution may be to create an alternative/extension selector for your button and change `vertical-align` to `baseline`:

```
[class^="icon-"] .my-class,
[class*=" icon-"] .my-class {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

But remember that the visual center depends on the word; "Dashboard" has for example no descenders (see more about [the anatomy of typography](http://www.fontshop.com/glossary/)). If `baseline` don't looks good try some of the others, see [specification here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vertical-align).

The suggested solution from @user1751766 is also possible. But I suggest to `.my-class` to scope this alternative declaration from Bootstrap's default declaration.

Comment: I can confirm that Google Fonts have something to do with this.

Answer (score 5):

Go to Bootstrap.css

```
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
```

Mess with `top` until it lines up the way you like. 11px worked for me on the heart, but it might depend on which icon / how you're trying to use it. Just tinker until it looks good.

Answer (score 4):

This has worked well for me:

```
span.glyphicon {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used CSS like this with Bootstrap in the past:

```
[class^="icon-"] {
margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Just play with the margin-top until it looks right.

Good luck!