# Center Twitter Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons in buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am now using Twitter Bootstrap 3 RC2 as well as Twitter Bootstrap which has moved into a separate repository. I have noticed, if used in  a button with text the icon is not centered very well:

[image]

The icon and the text have the same bottom line, but I believe for a good looking button the icon should be centered based on the text, shouldn't it? Any idea how to achieve this?

http://bootply.com/74652

Comment: I can't see the glyph in the example you provided. Do you mean you want the glyph and text both centered within the button?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Move the text out of the `<span>` with the glyphicon and apply `vertical-align: middle;` to the `<span>`

```
  <button class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th" style="vertical-align: middle;"></span> Centered
  </button>
```

**[Demo](http://bootply.com/74667)**

This works in Bootstrap 4 with Font Awesome icons like so

```
<button class="btn btn-default" style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Centered
</button>
```

Comment: I had a problem where the button wasn't shown with the same height as an input text paired inside an `input-group`. That problem was fixed with this solution, although the icon first appeared too low on the button. Using `vertical-align:top` fixed that.

Comment: Note: vertical-align middle may not always fix it, especially if your word has only ascenders (`f`, `t`) or descenders (`g`, `y`, `q`), as the middle of the vertical box of the word will not exactly align with the middle of the icon's vertical box.

Comment: Was about to go the hacky route and use an image instead (*yuck!*). Didn't know that the `vertical-align` property could be used for glyphs like this! Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Apply a `vertical-align: -{N}px;` style on the .glyphicon-th to shift it N pixels up/down.

Answer (score 3):

For some vertical-align might not work due to positioning: If you look into .glyphicon class you'll see it is set to relative, try setting it to 'inherit' e.g:

```
.glyphicon.v-centered {
    position: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This should also work for icons not in buttons, e.g. tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Try `vertical-align: middle;` on `.glyphicon-th:before`

Comment: With middle the text goes up and lines with the glyph icon bottom border. Sad, because it sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

None of the methods above worked well for me by themselves, but using `display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle` on the elements did. It's the `inline-block` that seems to be key.

```
.vcenter * {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

.btn i {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

with

```
<div class="vcenter">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span>Centered</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default"><span>Centered</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span>Centered</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
</div>
```

See http://www.bootply.com/UbY78zM8pD for live example.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it like this:

```
.glyphicon.center:before {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and use `<span class="glyphicon center glyphicon-th"></span>`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: Glyph icon was 2 px too high above the button text. Fixed it as follows using examples here. Thank you (Alastair Maw).

I managed to get mine working as follows:

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <a title="" class="btn btn-block btn-info oa-btn-spacer_homepage oa-ellipsis" role="button" href="default.aspx?action=page&name=creditcard">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card glyph_Credit"></span> Update Your Credit Card and Billing Information
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#panelTopic  .glyph_Credit {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom:6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-default">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th" style="font-size: 14px;"> </span>
          <span style="font-size: 17px;">Not Centered</span>
    </button>
```

please increase or decrease the font size according to your requirement

Comment: Way too much css... @Russ's answer is more practical.

Comment: "Way too much css"? There's only one property there. The `2nd` span is just an example.

Comment: What I meant was that tying the icons so tightly with the font-size is not good. I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that older comment :P

Answer (score 0):

Other way

```
<button class="btn default" id="IdBack">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-left"></i> 
  <b>Back</b>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a margin of the specific pixels or percentage. In my app, this worked beautifully, based on the dimensions of the area.

**CSS:**

```
.someWrapperClass button span {
    margin-top: 120%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="someWrapperClass">
    <button type="button" ng-click="SomeMethod()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```