# Align text with icon font in custom bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

I´m trying to align some text with an icon-font icon in a button with custom height. The icon and the text should both be in the vertical center of the button with some pixels padding to the left and right side so that they both are in the horizontal center of the button. It also seems that the attribute which sets the size of the icon also doesn´t work.

```css
/* Styles go here */
.btn-group{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#left, #middle, #right{
  height: 25px;
}

.button-content{
  
}

.button-icon{
  
}

.button-text{
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.button-text i{
  font-size: 12px; /* Change of icon-size doesn´t apply */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <div class="btn-group">
      <label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Left'" id="left">
        <span class="buton-content">
          <span class="button-icon"><i class="material-icons">info</i></span>
          <span class="button-text">CONTENT</span>
        </span>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Middle'" id="middle">
        <span class="buton-content">
          <span class="button-icon"><i class="material-icons">info</i></span>
          <span class="button-text">CONTENT</span>
        </span>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Right'" id="right">
        <span class="buton-content">
          <span class="button-icon"><i class="material-icons">info</i></span>
          <span class="button-text">CONTENT</span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

You can also find my code on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ctOmB2Cv2Ma8L58YeF68?p=preview).

---

**EDIT**

I fixed all issues besides the the fact that icon and text aren't in the vertical center of the button.

The Plunker was also updated.

---

**EDIT 2:**

The problem was fixed by using *@MarcosPérezGude* idea

```
#left, #middle, #right{
  height: 26px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;      
}
```

in addition to *@iyyappan* answer with the partial solution

```
.material-icons {vertical-align: middle;}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center Twitter Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons in buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273500/center-twitter-bootstrap-3-glyphicons-in-buttons)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked your codes.

**Please try it.**

```
#left, #middle, #right {
    height: auto;
}
.material-icons {vertical-align: middle;}
```

Comment: the alignment of the text and the icon works now but it just works with `height: auto`. I want to set the height of the button by myself. And why does the size of the icon doesn´t change ?

Comment: you are not able to change the height of the button with this mode, otherwise you'll obtain the error that you are trying to solve right now. Play with paddings but not with heights. Learn bootstrap first please

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thank you Marcos, the tipp with changing `padding` fixed the problem! I also updated the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ctOmB2Cv2Ma8L58YeF68?p=preview).

Comment: You are welcome. However, you must to practice more with bootstrap I guess :)

Comment: This solution helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `vertical-align: middle;` to the  `.material-icons` class.

```
 .material-icons {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this may help you and for changing the size of icon use font-size

```
#left, #middle, #right
{
height:26px;
}

.material-icons 
{
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:13px;
}

.btn
{
padding:2px 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .btn-group{
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }

    #left, #middle, #right{
      height: 25px;
    }

    .button-content{
      
    }

    .button-icon{
      
    }

    .button-text{
      vertical-align:middle;
    }

    .button-text i{
      font-size: 12px; /* Change of icon-size doesn´t apply */
    }
    #left, #middle, #right {
        height: auto;
    }
    .button-icon {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 0;
    }
     
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">











     <div class="btn-group">
          <label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Left'" id="left">
            <span class="buton-content">
              <span class="button-icon"><i class="material-icons">info</i></span>
              <span class="button-text">CONTENT</span>
            </span>
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Middle'" id="middle">
            <span class="buton-content">
              <span class="button-icon"><i class="material-icons">info</i></span>
              <span class="button-text">CONTENT</span>
            </span>
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Right'" id="right">
            <span class="buton-content">
              <span class="button-icon"><i class="material-icons">info</i></span>
              <span class="button-text">CONTENT</span>
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove below code from your custom css file style.css that is making issue of improper height.

```css
#left, #middle, #right {
    /* height: 26px; */
}
```

your custom css height is overriding the default bootstrap's buttons' height

> **Note:** Due to that you can't getting see your content in middle but
>   (Actually is there in middle).

[**Button size in Bootstrap Reference Link**](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp)

Comment: But I need the specific height of 26 pixels !

Comment: @JohnDizzle hii then you can use '.btn-xs' class with the lable that you have made button so that will work properly for you. here i attach the reference link for this please refer